# ASP ListBox wrong ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

So I have this 2 ListBox, everything works if I use only the second one, the problems start after clicking the first one, happens that the next time I click the second, it gets the ID of the firstone...

so..

click 2 -> Works

click 2 -> Works

click 1 -> works

click 1 -> works

click 2 -> I get the ID of the first one....

and I have this problem with all the browsers...

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="overflow:auto;">
    <label for="lbRoot" class="control-label">Root Cause</label> 
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbRoot" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="form-control" 
        Height="250px" 
        Width="170px"
        DataTextField="name" 
        DataValueField="file"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"
        AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3" style="overflow:auto;">
    <label for="lbEvidence" class="control-label ">Follow Up</label>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbEvidence" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="form-control" 
        Height="250px" 
        Width="170px"
        DataTextField="name" 
        DataValueField="file"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"
        AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

with this code behind

```
protected void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = "", value = "";
    ListBox x = sender as ListBox;
    if (x.ID == "lbRoot")
    {
        text = lbRoot.SelectedItem.Text;
        value = lbRoot.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
    else if (x.ID == "lbEvidence")
    {
        text = lbEvidence.SelectedItem.Text;
        value = lbEvidence.SelectedItem.Value;
    }


    //tried this for fixing the bug

    lbRoot.SelectedIndexChanged -= Index_Changed;
    lbRoot.SelectedIndex = -1;
    lbRoot.SelectedIndexChanged += Index_Changed;

    lbEvidence.SelectedIndexChanged -= Index_Changed;
    lbEvidence.SelectedIndex = -1;
    lbEvidence.SelectedIndexChanged += Index_Changed;

    doStuff(text, value);

}
```

Comment: You tagged this as `asp-classic`. I have removed that tag. Your code is ASP.NET, not [Classic ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages), which hasn't seen a release in years.

Comment: did you check with the debugger if your event doesn't trigger twice?

Comment: The other thing you could try is using two different `Index_Changed` callback methods.

Comment: yeah, originally had 2 methods, and lb2 entered the event of lb1, I thought I could differ IDs then I realized of the problem, and yep I use the debugger